# Google OAuth redirect_uri_mismatch when exchanging one-time-code for refresh token

Tags: java, scala, google-oauth

I'm implementing Google OAuth2 server one-time-code flow as described here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

The client gets the code from google (after user completes the oauth flow),
and POSTs it to the server.

The server tries to exchange the code for a refresh token (using the Java SDK) using this call:

```
val authorizationScopes = Seq(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY, GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND, "email").asJavaCollection

val googleAuthorizationCodeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
      GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
      JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance,
      googleAppInfo.googleClientId,
      googleAppInfo.googleClientSecret,
      authorizationScopes)
  .setTokenServerUrl(new GenericUrl(googleAppInfo.tokenServerUrl))
  .setAccessType("offline")
  .build()

val googleTokenResponse: GoogleTokenResponse = googleAuthorizationCodeFlow
  .newTokenRequest(code)
  .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
  .execute()
```

I get:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request {  "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch",  "error_description" : "Bad Request"}

The redirectUri is exactly the same as in the Google cloud console > Credentials > Client Id (Web Application) > Authorized redirect URIs.

Also, it already worked when we used the OAuth redirect flow, but when we switched to the POST flow, it stopped working with this message.

I tried sending an empty redirectUri (as I saw in some answers about the matter), but than I get:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request {  "error" : "Missing required parameter: redirect_uri",  "error_description" : "Bad Request"}

I even tried sending the actual 'referer' url.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not documented but when you work with Google client SDK you don't redirect.

The SDK opens a new windows and communicate with it using post message.

If you set the redirect uri as `"postmessage"` it should work for you.

Comment: I have been looking for hours on how to fix this issue. Your solution is the only one that works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are getting that error when using [popup mode](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model#popup-mode), the solution was having the same redirect_uri both in the front- and back- end.

I.e. Front-

```
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  redirect_uri: 'postmessage',
  some_other_params,
})

client.requestCode()
```

Back-

```
export const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  clientId,
  clientSecret,
  "postmessage"
)

let { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code)
```