# "redirect_uri_mismatch" when exchanging access token under "popup" mode

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

We build our web application and integrate with Google OAuth2 according to this doc [Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model#popup-mode)

We would like to use "popup" mode, but when trying to exchange access_token with authentication code, `/token` return error like "

> {"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch","error_description": "Bad Request"}"

We have passed the `redirect_url` param when calling `/token`, and it is exactly the same one as configured on the credential page.

What's more weird is that when we switch to "redirect" mode, everything works fine. Same `client_id`, same `client_secret`, same `grant_type`, same `redirect_uri`.

I don't get it, it's like codes generated under `redirect` and `popup` mode are treated differently.

Any help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The redirect uri must exactly match one you have registered in Google developer console for your project.  The error message should tell you what is missing.  Can you post the full error message as well as what you have set in google developer console.

Comment: What redirect url did you specify?

Comment: @DaImTo  This is what I get from Google: {"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch","error_description": "Bad Request"}"

Comment: @DeltaGeorge I specify the same one in "redirect" mode, in which everything works fine

Comment: @EricZheng I encountered exactly the same error. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the redirectUri in the OAuth2 client to "postmessage" to indicate that you've already sent the message.

It's an undocumented feature.

[Google OAuth redirect_uri_mismatch when exchanging one-time-code for refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222501/google-oauth-redirect-uri-mismatch-when-exchanging-one-time-code-for-refresh-tok?rq=1)

You should delete the existing redirect URLs in the google console, and re-download the credentials JSON.

Comment: man, you really saved me! It works

Comment: i have been trying this but for some reason , it just doesn't work :/

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying to fix this issue for a week now and after hitting this post it works!!!! GOOGLE if your reading this you need to fix your docs -> https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model#popup-mode points to https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code and in the second link you MUST SAY THAT THE REDIRECT MESSAGE needs to be "postmessage" and the API client needs no redirect urls.

Answer (score 2):

As per doc you referenced, Google is not expecting a refirect_url in popup mode. Google will not send a redirect. Instead it will return auth code directly to your callback and the callback will have to send it to your server.

Comment: Yes, but `redirect_url` is required when exchanging access_token with code

Comment: That is true.I am away from my laptop atm to try.  Perhaps the library you are using sends another parameter that removes that requirement. Another option is to send an empty one, perhaps.

Comment: @EricZheng that depends upon the grant type actually.   Popup probably has an internal redirect uri set.

Comment: @DaImTo I have tried both sending an empty one and removing `redirect_url`, still don't work. What do you mean by "has an internal redirect uri set" ? I have also tried specifying "postmessage".