# Google OAuth2 throws out "redirect_uri_mismatch" error even for an exact match

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

My app already work for OAuth2 implicit flow. I am trying to make it work for authorized code flow but I encountered an error of "redirect_uri_mismatch". The part I don't understand is that the "redirect_uri" in fact matches exactly what is specified in the API console.  Here is the curl command I ran, where the  `code` is obtained via `google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient` with popup mode.

```
curl -X POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token \
      --data-urlencode "code=${code}" \
      --data-urlencode "redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/api/gcode" \
      --data-urlencode "client_id=${cid}" \
      --data-urlencode "client_secret=${cs}"  \
      --data-urlencode "grant_type=authorization_code"
```

which gives me an error:

```
{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

The redirect_uri matches exactly one of the specified uri in the API console: [image: snapshot].

What did I miss? I have already checked some old posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch?rq=1) but none of the solutions works for my case.

**Update**:
The problem seem to be related to that popup ux mode works differently than the redirect ux mode. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968377/redirect-uri-mismatch-when-exchanging-access-token-under-popup-mode) reports the same problem.

Comment: I had this issue once.. even after 24 hours it was not working. So I ended up creating a new application credential and that worked.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w  <-- that might help.  Just use http://127.0.0.1 as your redirect uri instead and make sure you are using a native client on google developer console and not a web client.